# How to get gravatar in wordpress post using php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I know the get_avatar() function but its not working. Maybe its due to the complexity of the loops? Please take a look at the code below and let me know! Thanks!

```
function displaymeta(){
        global $post;
        $m_meta_description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_meta_box_check', 
                                            true);
        global $wpdb;
        $user_nicenames = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id,user_nicename FROM 
        {$wpdb->prefix}users", ARRAY_N);

        foreach($user_nicenames as $nice_name) 
        {
            foreach($nice_name as $name) 
            {
                foreach($m_meta_description as $val)
                {
                    $flag=strcmp($name,$val);
                    if($flag==0)
                    {
                        echo"<li>";
                        echo $name. "<br>";
                        echo get_avatar($name->ID,50);
                        echo"</li>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'displaymeta' );
```

I've tried $name,$nice_name, $user_nicenames in function get_avatar($val->ID,50); but nothing seems to work! What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Are you getting any error messages? If so, let us know what it is. And if not, are you sure that it's the `get_avatar()` function that's failing or maybe they are just not passing your if statement?

Comment: @DirkScholten Yes it is passing through my if statement, because the echo $name; is working fine. But I cannot get the gravatars to appear on my post. Only the default gravatar is showing up. And yes I've checked in the settings, and avatars are enabled.

Comment: get_avatar only takes an ID or an email.  Have you tested within your code that $name->ID actually returns a value? Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

Comment: Apparently, $name->ID does not return anything

Comment: @KomalR it doesn't "return" anything because `$name` is not an `object`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already used the right `function`, which is `get_avatar()`.

But the problem is that the **`$name` as in `get_avatar($name->ID,50)` is not an `object`**. Instead, it's a `string`, which could be the user ID *or* display name (i.e. the `user_nicename` column in the WordPress users table).

So try replacing the `foreach` in your `displaymeta()` function with the one below, where I assigned `$name` to `$nice_name[1]`, and the user ID is assigned to `$user_id`:

```
foreach($user_nicenames as $nice_name) 
{
    $user_id = $nice_name[0];
    $name = $nice_name[1];

    foreach($m_meta_description as $val)
    {
        $flag=strcmp($name,$val);
        if($flag==0)
        {
            echo"<li>";
            echo $name. "<br>";
            echo get_avatar($user_id,50);
            echo"</li>";
        }
    }
}
```

### Additional Note

If you remove the `, ARRAY_N` as in: *(but you don't have to remove it. These are just extra info..)*

```
$user_nicenames = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id,user_nicename FROM 
{$wpdb->prefix}users", ARRAY_N);
```

then the variable `$nice_name` would be an `object`. Hence you can then access `$nice_name->user_nicename` like this:

```
$user_id = $nice_name->id;
$name = $nice_name->user_nicename;
```

---

### UPDATE

In reply to your comment on the missing content, it's because you didn't capture the variable that WordPress passes through the `the_content` filter. And you also need to append the `LI`'s to that `$content`, and finally `return` the modified content (i.e. `$content`).

So try this code *(which is already utilizing the **new** `foreach` code as I provided before or above)*:

```
function displaymeta( $content ){
    global $post;
    $m_meta_description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_meta_box_check', 
                                        true);
    global $wpdb;
    $user_nicenames = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id,user_nicename FROM 
    {$wpdb->prefix}users", ARRAY_N);

    // Add the opening UL tag. Remove if not needed.
    $content .= '<ul>';

    foreach($user_nicenames as $nice_name) 
    {
        $user_id = $nice_name[0];
        $name = $nice_name[1];

        foreach($m_meta_description as $val)
        {
            $flag=strcmp($name,$val);
            if($flag==0)
            {
                $content .= "<li>";
                $content .= $name. "<br>";
                $content .= get_avatar($user_id,50);
                $content .= "</li>";
            }
        }
    }

    // Add the closing UL tag. Remove if not needed.
    $content .= '</ul>';

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'displaymeta' );
```

Hope that helps! =)

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks Sally, I'll see how it works for me.

Comment: Sure, take your time. And FYI, you could also use just `$wpdb->users` than the need to use `{$wpdb->prefix}` as in `{$wpdb->prefix}users`.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks :)

Comment: Sally, you made my day! Thanks it works perfect! :) Cheers!

Comment: PS: I edited my answer - I replaced the `$nice_name->ID` with `$nice_name->id`. Just a small typo, but I thought it would be helpful to correct it. ;)

Comment: I didn't remove the ARRAY_N so didn't make much difference but now I removed and made the changes as you said. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Hey when I execute this code, the only content on my post is the name of author with its avatar. I want this to appear after the content of the post. The post content is missing. Can you help me?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Try it out, and if it works, perhaps you can upvote my answer?.. ;)

Comment: I'm making such silly mistakes! ha after all I'm a begineer! haha thanks Sally works like a charm. And I upvoted your answer before I even checked it ;)

Comment: Even a non-beginner like me still sometimes make *dumb* mistakes! So it's alright, we all learn from our mistakes.. =) And btw, thanks for the "blind" upvote! I truly appreciate it very much. :)

Comment: Yes, that's true. And after all the help you've done for me, you really deserved that upvote! :-)

Comment: Yep, I surely do deserve it! Haha just kidding. So all the best and I'm going to upvote the question for your effort. ;) Cheers!

Comment: But I wasn't kidding :D haha thanks! And good luck helping people all over the world! :) Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178205/discussion-between-komal-r-and-sally-cj).